# $\lim X_n = 0$ iff $b > 0$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, normal-distribution, uniform-integrability

Probability with Martingales:

---

[image]

---

It looks like $$\lim \exp\{aS_n - bn\} = 0$$ if $b > 0$ because

$$\lim aS_n - bn = -\infty \tag{*}$$

but how to prove $(*)$?

Comment: Do you sincerely believe that the almost sure limit $\lim \exp\{aS_n - bn\}$ may exist?

Comment: Hint: $$\exp(aS_n-b_n) = \exp(S_n)^a\exp(b)^{-n}$$

Comment: @Math1000 ah thanks. Now I guess I see intuitively but how to prove rigourously? bn would seem to grow without bound but while aS_n oscillates.

Comment: Do you sincerely believe that $\exp(b)^{-n}$ "grows without bound"?

Comment: @Math1000 huh? $$\lim e^{-bn} = 0$$ if $b>0$ right?

Comment: @Math1000 Edited post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, rewrite the exponenent as 
\begin{align*}
\exp \left( n\left( a\frac{S_n}{n} - b \right) \right)
\end{align*}
By the Law of Large Numbers, we have $a S_n/n- b \to a \mathbb{E}(\xi_1) - b$ a.s..
So $a S_n -bn \to - \infty$ a.s. if and ony if $b>a \mathbb{E}(\xi_1) =0$, and thus
\begin{align*}
\exp( a S_n - b n ) \to 0 \text{ iff } b > 0.
\end{align*}